# Do emulator programs like Bluestacks, Memu, Genymotion use the real device settings of the computer you're connecting from?

Tags: fingerprinting

Many online services use fingerprinting to track users - storing enough hardware and software details to create a unique record.

But what do emulators do? Can they make you completely anonymous on the internet?
Do Bluestacks or Memu use the physical device settings or do they use something else that will help avoid this tracking?

I'm a novice in this world of emulating and I just wish to understand a little bit.

Comment: Edited to focus on the question you asked in the headline